# Converting hard way ajax to $.ajax jquery

Tags: ajax

I am new to AJAX, I began studying the harder way of calling ajax unaware of the easier way of doing it until someone commented on my code that there is an easy of calling an AJAX. Can someone convert this to the $.ajax way :D. thank you!

this is my function that call an AJAX

```
function showResult(str)
{
    if (str.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2"; 
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You could have a look at the jQuery [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax), for instance. Someone will undoubtedly point out that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont forget to include the jquery file

```
var variable = '123'; //here you should pass the veriable to server
        $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : getuser.php,
                    data : variable 
                }).done(function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    }
                });
```

1. type should be GET Or POST
2. url: path to your file
3. data:  for sending to server
4. done: when your response is return from server

[You should read this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)